# Hard reset for Samsung T550

Tags: factory-reset

When I tried to hard restart my Galaxy tablet this is the message I got on the screen

OOIN MODE
PRODUCT NAME: SM-T550
CURRENT BINARY: Samsung Official
SYSTEM STATUS: Official
WARRANTY VOID: 0X0
QUALCOMM SECUREBOOT: ENABLE (CSB)
AP SWREV: S1, T1, H1, R1, A1, P1
SECURE DOWNLOAD: ENABLE

There is an arrow pointing down that says
Downloading
Do Not turn off target

Comment: you can safely turn off your device. if you wanted recovery mode try again with other Volume Key. Be aware this device has FRP Factory Reset Protection, that mean even after successful reset it is locked. you need to unlock with bonded google play account afterwards